# Druid Kafka ingestion with read-your-writes

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I'm learning Druid now. I read that ingestion via Kafka Indexing Service guarantees exactly-once semantics.

However, I have a problem with determining consistency model of Druid. Typically streams are asynchronous, but I want to have read-your-writes semantics in application.

Is there any possibility to check Druid's ingestion status? For example, I send event A and want to check if it was already saved in Druid. If yes, query to Druid should return result with this value.

Maybe there is some other possibility to do real-time ingestion with exactly-once semantics and with read-your-writes?

Answer (score 2):

Druid has separate process for ingestion and reading the data. read-your-writes won't be directly possible, however you can get the success for writes, and than you can make a separate query for reading your write.

check out tranquility server, which gives an http based gateway to write in real-time and it tries to handle exactly once ingestion too.

Though the best approach to ensure exactly once ingestion is to do reindexing by batch ingestion at regular interval depending on your use case.